# Disable comma or dot based on device locale in android

Tags: java, android, keyboard

How can I disable dot(.) key or comma(,) key in android based on the locale language selected on the device.
I need to use dot for English and comma for Swedish or other languages that support comma instead of dot.

Comment: is your input field is number filed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DigitsKeyListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/DigitsKeyListener#getInstance(java.lang.String)) from Android.

For Ex,

If English,

```
editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890."));
```

If swedish,

```
editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890,"));
```

> Note that this EditText will only accepts the characters you specified in
>   this String. So whatever chars you want you have to add it to here.

Comment: or use in xml
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890,"
OR
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890."